# Change output based on text field value

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I need to change the output of my custom fields based on whether or not there is a specific word in the text field.

For example, I need to show the French flag if a text field contains the word "France." Is that a possibility, and how would I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

```
$string = get_field( 'your_field_name' );
if (strpos($string , 'France') !== false) {
   // do your thing
}
```

*You can use the [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) for case-insensitive.*